# Flatten surface on inclination

Tags: modeling

Trying to model a Hull of a sailboat, but i get this line in the middle. I use Mirror modifier, and in intersection the line appears. Is there any way to solve this?
[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Just to be sure: Have you checked the "merge" option in the mirror modifier?

Comment: Hello,
@moonboots link to model:
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5BKolS3m" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5BKolS3m/)
I have used merge option.
The flat surface topology is problematic  mostly at the bottom of the Stern (the end of the ship). Although I am pretty new to blender. Might be I am missing some refined edge crease. What do you think?

Comment: This might be location to my model. Sorry for bad link in 1st comment.
https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/37xZx1BP

Comment: I can't see the problem in the linked file, that said you have a ngon that creates artifacts, you can easily fix it if you create quads. Also you use crease, I don't, I prefer to use edge loops to sharp the edges

Comment: @moonboots can you be more specific, and indicate which place in my problematic surface has an ngon? If you are talking about the top, I added that cut later. The problem is in the bottom. That loop does not affect the problem. You are free to try making changes yourself and see my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the linked file I can't see the same thing as you, but for example you have this artifact:

[image]

It's because you have ngons, face with more than 5 vertices, which tends to create artifacts, especially on non-flat surfaces (it stretches the triangles):

[image]

Here is a way to fix it, there might be a better but it's just to show you how to keep quads:

[image]

Also, you use crease and *Bevel* modifier, if you begin in modeling perhaps you should bevel "manually" instead, and avoid crease and *Bevel* modifier, they are tricks and you won't always be able to use them, but it's only my opinion...